# Python, asyncio, non deterministic results

Tags: python, api, asynchronous, networking, request

I have the following problem that my code for api requests is really non deterministic. I use `asyncio` to make asynchronous requests, because I want to send multiple requests and have big frequency of changes(that's why I am sending 30 the same requests). Sometimes my code executes really quickly about 0.5s but sometimes it stucks after sending for example a half of the requests. Could anyone see some code bugs which can produce the following error? Or such thing is caused by some delays of the server responses?

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        data = await response.json()
        print(data)
        return await response.read()

async def run(r):
    url = "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/"
    tasks = []


    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(r):
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(url.format(i), session))
            tasks.append(task)
        responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await responses

t1 = time.time()
number = 30
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(number))
loop.run_until_complete(future)

t2= time.time()
print(t2-t1)
```